# Split the word in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, split

I am checking to see if an underscore (`_`) is present in a given string or not. If it is found, I want to split the word into two values (a value present before underscore and a value present after underscore).

```
DECLARE @ExpressionToSearch VARCHAR(50) 
    SET @ExpressionToSearch = 'TMS_Customers'
    IF  CHARINDEX('_', @ExpressionToSearch ) > 0 
        PRINT 'Yes it Contains'
    ELSE
        PRINT 'It doesn''t Contain'

Required output
---------------
a=TMS
b=Customers
```

how can i split the given string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capture the `CHARINDEX` result the use it to read the text surrounding `_`

```
DECLARE @ExpressionToSearch VARCHAR(50)
SET @ExpressionToSearch = 'TMS_Customers'

DECLARE @Position INT = CHARINDEX('_', @ExpressionToSearch)       

IF (@POSITION = 0) BEGIN
    PRINT 'It doesn''t Contain'
    RETURN
END

SELECT 
    LEFT(@ExpressionToSearch, @Position - 1),
    RIGHT(@ExpressionToSearch, LEN(@ExpressionToSearch) - @Position)
```

Answer (score 0):

What is a and b? What if there are more than 1 _ in string. A flexible way would be to get those values as rows instead. ie:

```
DECLARE @ExpressionToSearch VARCHAR(50) 
SET @ExpressionToSearch = 'TMS_Customers'
IF  CHARINDEX('_', @ExpressionToSearch ) > 0 
    PRINT 'Yes it Contains'
ELSE
    PRINT 'It doesn''t Contain'

DECLARE @sep CHAR(1) = '_'
SET @ExpressionToSearch = @sep+@ExpressionToSearch +@sep;

SELECT SUBSTRING(@ExpressionToSearch,N+1,CHARINDEX(@sep,@ExpressionToSearch,N+1)-N-1) AS [Value]
FROM (
 SELECT N FROM (VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6)) t(N)) t
WHERE N < LEN(@ExpressionToSearch) AND 
SUBSTRING(@ExpressionToSearch,N,1) = @sep;
```

Note: 6 is an arbitrarily chosen value, if needed that can be selected from joining sys.columns for too many rows.